# Mecabが文字化けとUnicodeDecodeErrorが発生

Tags: mecab

OS:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS、Mecabバージョン0.996にての質問です。

最初にここの説明通りにインストールしました：http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#install-unix

しかし、上記の問題が発生したためにここの説明を参考にしてやり直しました：
https://qiita.com/junpooooow/items/0a7d13addc0acad10606

`./configure --with-charset=utf8`の手順で以下”Missing"が発生します。

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for mecab-config... /usr/local/bin/mecab-config
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

そのまま

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

しても上記の問題が発生し続けています（多分当たり前の話ですが）。
解決法を知っている方アドバイスをお願いします。

**追記：**
http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1343137403 を参考にして辞書を以下のように指定すると、文字化けが無くなります。

```
mecab -d /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8
```

うれしいのですが、毎回入力せずに済む方法（辞書の指定を固定させる）はありますか。

Comment: できれば実行環境（OSの種類）やインストールしようとしているMeCabのバージョンも記載しておきましょう。後からでも[編集]で追記することができます。

Comment: nkf を使った変換や dicrc の編集もしたんですよね?

Comment: nkfとdicrcは実施しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> うれしいのですが、毎回入力せずに済む方法（辞書の指定を固定させる）はありますか。

[Mecabのシステム辞書・ユーザ辞書の利用方法について](https://qiita.com/hiro0217/items/cfcf801023c0b5e8b1c6) によると、
`/usr/local/etc/mecabrc`に以下のように設定することで、システム辞書の場所を指定できるようです。

```
dicdir =  /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

`./configure`実行時には、これからコンパイル・インストールしようとしているソフトウェアに必要なものが揃っているかを確認しており、`missing`と出ている場合は足りないものを確認しつつ事前にインストールしなければいけません。

質問の環境で足りていないのは以下のパッケージになると思うので、お使いの環境に合わせて確認、インストールしてみてください。

- **automake** (aclocal, automake)
- **texinfo** (makeinfo)

Comment: texinfoはお陰様でインストールできましたが、何故かautomakeとaclocalはすでに最新版がインストール済みだと表示されました。